Downvotes and the lack of user involvement, we should do better than this
We all agree that bad questions should be downvoted and deleted.
However it seems the common courtesy of treating the person who asked a question with respect is lacking.
Downvoting is anonymous, so people have no repercussions other than -1 reputation.

To my understanding there are 2 issues right now within our stack exchange.

People downvote "heresy" type questions regardless of validity or not. (THat is to say, they dislike the question)
People downvote without attempting to improve what is likely a valid question that is simply lacking detail or similar.


I am mostly focused on the 2nd one right now. We have a relatively high standard (as far as the internet is concerned) on quality of content. But some people downvote without attempting to help the "asker". What good does this really do? Why do I login every few days and see "a new contributor" being downvoted into oblivion without someone popping up and guiding them even slightly?
I know I get frustrated at people who just copy and paste that "welcome to the site, check out the tour, learn how to post..." because I am more individually targeting the issues in the post.

Regarding the first, I'm sure there is not much we can do about it other then moderators keeping the question open despite negative votes. (For example my question about magic, technically on topic barely but no one wanted to touch it)

This just a permanent problem we must endure? If so let me know, so I can set my expectations accordingly.

Oh, dear.  It seems your question has been down-voted without any explanation, which tends to prove your point.
I agree that contributors should explain why they are down-voting a question thereby giving an opportunity for the question to be edited and improved.
Personally, I seldom down-vote and if it's a new contributor I will either edit the question to improve it or leave a comment to explain why the question might be closed.
You ask if this is a permanent problem we must endure. In my experience, the moderators are usually helpful and patient, especially with new contributors. I wonder if the difficulty has arisen because there are many more new contributors who may be down-voting indiscriminately.
Another aspect may simply be that there are not enough moderators to cope with the volume of low quality and spam posts. from new contributors.
I've just discovered that one contributor has had  188 down-votes to 230 answers, and 76 down-votes to 67 questions asked. If that isn't a case of targeted down-voting, I don't know what is!
All I can suggest is that you persevere and continue to set a good example.

The down vote without any comment did amuse my sense of irony. I believe the mods usually spend the extra 5s to write a reason. :)

At least you can take comfort knowing that you have not been targeted by serial down-voters :-)  !
